# Removing time stamp when converting date format with dateparser in scrapy

Tags: python, datetime, scrapy

I am using [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) in scrapy to convert the date format.

Original date format: `Apr 16, 2019`

After using dateparser: `2019-04-16  00:00:00`

This is what I wanted to achieve. However, I would still like to remove the time from the date format, so in the end, I only have `2019-04-16`. Unfortunately, I am not able to realize this.

This is my line of code:

```
import dateparser

...

def parse_site(self, response):
        def get_with_xpath(query):
             return response.xpath(query).get(default='').strip()
        yield {
            'date': dateparser.parse(get_with_xpath('//meta[@name="date"]/@content'))
        }
```

As I said, it works. But the time stamp I would like to remove. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dateparser.parse returns datetime representing parsed date if successful. You can use strftime() function to remove the timestamp as shown below

`dateparser.parse('Apr 16, 2019').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 1):

Methods of this library return all values in `datetime` format. But afterwards you are free to do with them anything you want. Check this example:

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse("Apr 16, 2019")
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 16, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse("Apr 16, 2019").date()
datetime.date(2019, 4, 16)
```